# dom-if issue with Polymer 1.x

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a couple of conditionally stamped elements inside a template repeater. Now when I update the data, the if-conditions don't seem to take effect, which results in `undefined` getting passed into the functions which handle the data for those elements.

Using the `restamp` property didn't seem to help (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-if). So far I was only able to solve this by emptying the items property (`this.items = [];`) inside my change handler which initiates a new request.

This works, but results in the template being empty for a short amount of time before the new data gets displayed. Not necessarily a problem, but I wonder if I'm doing something wrong.

Here are the corresponding parts of the code:

```
<template>
...
<iron-ajax
  id="ironajax"
  url="https://www.url.com/api"
  params="{{ajaxParams}}"
  handle-as="json"
  on-response="handleResponse"
  on-error="handleError">
</iron-ajax>
...
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}" id="items">
...
<template is="dom-if" if="{{item.info.subtitle}}">: 
  <span>{{truncateSubtitle(item.info.subtitle)}}</span
</template>
...
Polymer({
  is: 'my-element',
  properties: {
    query: {
      type: String,
      value: ''
    }
    ...
    items: {
      type: Array,
      value: []
    }
  }
  ...
  handleChange: function() {
    if (this.value !== '') {
      this.items = [];
      this.query = this.value;
      this.$.ironajax.generateRequest();
    }
  }
...
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 4):

Given `"{{item.info.subtitle}}"`, if `item.info` is `null` or `undefined` or if `item.info.subtitle` is `undefined`, the binding will not refresh and may have a stale value (in the context of a repeat where nodes are re-used).

Polymer doesn't perform calculations on `undefined` values because it's a performance enhancement in a large number of cases, however it can be tricky in this scenario.

You should use a function to resolve the correct state. Something like

```
if="{{hasSubtitle(item)}}"
```

and

```
hasSubtitle function(item) {
  return item.info && item.info.subtitle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Just curious that why we need `{{}}` or `[[]]` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The "if" property of "dom-if" requires a Boolean.

Try creating a polymer property that will be set to true or false if "item.info.subtitle" is not empty or null.

Then use the created property with dom-if:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{hasSubtitle}}" >
```

reference:  http://polymer.github.io/polymer/ --> dom-if (dropdown)

---

Additional info: Added on June 10th

Try using a property instead of a method.

Declare your property like this:

```
Polymer({
    is: "my-element",
    properties: {
        hasSubtitle: {
            type: Boolean,
            value: 'false',  //false or true, the more common case.
        }
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks sam_dw. I put a method inside "if" which returns a boolean. But that doesn't seem to solve the issue...

Comment: @north, try a property instead of a method.
Check my answer again, I'm adding new info.

Comment: Thanks a lot sam_dw, but the issue remains. I might be doing something wrong. Having to create these properties also seems to be quite a bit of a detour compared to simply passing the JSON response to the template.

Comment: Did you check if you are properly retrieving the JSON?
Have you tried to use "lastResponse" to access the data?
Take a look on this demo code:
https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/blob/master/demo/index.html

Comment: Thanks once more, sam_dw. Using "lastResponse" doesn't seem to make a difference either. Receiving the JSON is not the problem I'd say, because if I reset "this.items" everything is fine. For some reason dom-if is not working for me. BTW: my code used to work fine with Polymer 0.5, core-ajax and the former template if implementation.